# ASMX with SharePoint 2010 and folder structure

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, content-and-structure, asmx

I am trying to convert my current ASP.net application to a SharePoint 2010 site. I have few questions before I start moving stuff from my ASP.net application to a SharePoint solution.

1. My current web app has a asmx service that I use to define web methods which are called by ajax calls from my web pages. How I can do the same in SharePoint. Is it adviceable to use asmx or I should use WCF?
2. I have some classes in my web app, should I create a class library project in my SharePoint solution or is there any way so I could add my classes under some folder structure?

Whats the best approach for having all this stuff together? In different projects or in SharePoint project .

Kindly advice?

Answer (score 1):

If you have asmx services you can deploy that on your Sharepoint server. As sharepoint 2010 supports both, it,s upto you if you want to use as at asmx or WCF. For you second query, You can add your code as same library project but deploy the Dll to Gac.

There are various options to migrate your Asp.net application to Sharepoint:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21465/Converting-an-ASP-NET-site-into-a-SharePoint-site

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c612bcd-c403-4157-b5dd-a7a1f9f8b17b/migrating-an-existing-aspnet-application-to-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Blank SharePoint Project. In that project you package the dll along with wsp.

When deploying external DLLs, which shall also be put into the GAC or somewhere else, you need to package them with the WSP aswell. This has become very easy with Visual Studio 2010:

Open your Package
Click on "Advanced" (on the bottom)
Add your external DLL and maybe even SafeControls for the web.config

For webservice, as it is already created you should just deploy it in _vti bin of SharePoint

%COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\ISAPI